# A fast numpy way to find index in array where cumulative sum becomes greater?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Basically, the *logic* of my problem is:

```
running_sum = my_array.cumsum()
greater_than_threshold = running_sum > threshold
index = greater_than_threshold.searchsorted(True)
```

That is: Find the first index for which the cumulative sum of entries in `my_array` is above a threshold.

Now the problem is: I know that `my_array` will be large, but that the condition will be met fairly early. Of course that means I could just do a simple `while` loop to manually figure out when the cumulative sum is larger than the threshold, but I am wondering if there's a numpythonic way, i.e., a way to test for some condition without having the entire array evaluated.

Comment: For one, you can search for the threshold directly: `index = running_sum.searchsorted(threshold)`.

Comment: If you need to optimize for performance, you might also consider iterating over slices of the array, and performing the computation on each slice.

Comment: *"my_array will be large"*  How large, roughly?  One million? 100 million?  *"...the condition will be met fairly early"*  How early, roughly?  First 25%? 10%?   1%?  Knowing these parameters will help people focus on an appropriate method for improving the performance.  (For example, some optimizations might not improve performance unless the number of entries is greater than a million or so.)

Comment: Large = at least 50000, Early = Definitely within first 1%

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: This method is slower than using NumPy's `searchsorted` and `cumsum`, see user2357112's comments and `timeit` test.

`cumsum` will calculate cumulative sums for the entire array. Instead, just iterate over the array yourself:

```
running_sum = 0
for index, entry in enumerate(my_array.flat):
    running_sum += entry
    if running_sum > threshold:
        break
if running_sum < threshold:
    index = -1 #if the sum never reaches the threshold
```

Comment: ... why the `index` thing? `for index, entry in enumerate(my_array.flat):`

Comment: Iterating over the array manually is going to be far slower than NumPy's `cumsum`, so this only makes sense if you're expecting the threshold to be reached very early in a large array.

Comment: @user2357112 the OP said the condition should be met "easily", which I assumed meant early.

Comment: It really does have to be extremely early, though. For example, [`numpy.cumsum` still wins for `threshold=10` and `my_array=numpy.ones(1000)`](http://ideone.com/CVzr8X).

Comment: @user2357112 I don't know the workings of NumPy well, in that case it might be better to just use `cumsum` in all cases. @Bakuriu edited to use `enumerate`.

Comment: Wow, thanks for doing the timing. That's pretty impressive and just goes to show how awesome numpy is. I usually try to really drive the point home when I'm teaching someone about numpy: Never manually iterate when you can use numpy. I just kinda expected that in this case surely there'd be an exception